# Cant get any Ubuntu to install to an internal hard drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I am trying to install Ubuntu Studio on some of my computers. 
When I run the installer I get to the "Installation type" page and it is blank. 
There is no device shown. 
I have tried this on multiple systems as well as different ubuntu distros. 
I have even manually partitioned and erased the hard drive and then attempted installation with no success.
I can run all live from the DVD's with no problem, but the moment I start the installation the hard drive icons on the desktop disappear and it can not find any device for installation. Also windows installs without any issues.

I am an extreme noob when it comes to Ubuntu. Please any help is greatly appreciated as I have been struggling for days now.

Thanx

Computers used with installation:

Dell Optiplex 390 - i3 2120 with 8gb ram 250gb HDD - on chip Intel graphics

Asus - AM3 Phenom II x4 955 - 8gb ram 250gb HDD - HD7790 Ati

Dell Optiplex 380 - Intel E7500 - 8gb ram 250gb HDD - on board graphics

When I select the "Install Ubuntu Studio" icon on the desktop, the first thing I notice is the shortcuts to the HDD on the desktop disappears. Then about 5 seconds later the "Install" window opens on the welcome page with a list of languages. I click "Continue" The next window is "prepare to install Ubuntu Studio" on it is two options.Download Updates while installing and Install third-party software. I click continue. Next is the Ubuntu Studio Installation options page. I click continue. Then I get to the Installation type page with a block with columns - Device, Type,Mount Point, Format?,Size ect. All the columns are empty. Below this there is a three blocks with "+","-" and "change" (if you click on any of these the installation gives you an installation error and then quits) below these there is a selectable block with /dev/sda in. Selecting this does nothing.  Then there is an "Install Now" button, when selected this button it jumps to the "Something Else" menu and then I get the "No root file system is defined, please correct from the partitioning menu" error. And this is as far as it will go. The moment you exit the shortcuts for the HDD on the desktop re-appears.

Here is the requested codes

```
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~/Desktop$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             4020036       0   4020036   0% /dev
tmpfs             807172    9368    797804   2% /run
/dev/sr0         2755376 2755376         0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0       2708352 2708352         0 100% /rofs
aufs             4035848   96464   3939384   3% /
tmpfs            4035848     108   4035740   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       8      5112   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            4035848       0   4035848   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            4035848       8   4035840   1% /tmp
tmpfs             807172      40    807132   1% /run/user/999
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~/Desktop$ 

ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~/Desktop$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL             UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sr0    iso9660 Ubuntu-Studio 16.04.2 LTS amd64
                             2017-02-15-21-17-59-00               /cdrom
loop0  squashf                                                        /rofs
sda    ddf_rai                   LSI     \x80\x86)%                   
â”œâ”€sda2 ext4                      03a31caa-1f23-49d8-955e-9c92c42c3b1d 
â”œâ”€sda3 swap                      1e498aab-a4e3-46bc-84f4-4850962f2eae 
â””â”€sda1 ext4                      20bce372-f814-40df-8a51-0fd3eefe7c56 
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~/Desktop$ 

ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~/Desktop$ sudo lsblk -m
NAME     SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sr0      2.6G root  cdrom brw-rw----
loop0    2.6G root  disk  brw-rw----
sda     232.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
sda2    229.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
sda3     2G   root  disk  brw-rw----
sda1     1G   root  disk  brw-rw----
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~/Desktop$ 

ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~/Desktop$ sudo parted -ls
Model: ATA ST3250318AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  1076MB  1075MB  primary  ext4            boot
 2      1076MB  248GB   247GB   primary  ext4
 3      248GB   250GB   2147MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).          /dev/sr0 has been opened read-only.
Model: HL-DT-ST DVD+-RW GH70N (scsi)
Disk /dev/sr0: 2822MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: mac
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name   Flags
 1      2048B   6143B   4096B                Apple
 2      7320kB  9810kB  2490kB               EFI


ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~/Desktop$
```

I think it is best if I paste the screen captures of the installation then you can see the **difference**

[The fourth window and here everything goes pear shaped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RLQE.jpg)

[This happens when I hit "Install"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNl4d.jpg)

The installer crashes to the desktop when I hit either "+" "-" or "Change"

Comment: Have you checked that the iso file and the DVD disk are good? See this link, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13511608#post13511608 ? Which version number of Ubuntu Studio are you trying to install? Have you tried another version? Maybe you can try standard Ubuntu?

Comment: I am trying to install Studio 16.04. I have check the DVD disks and they are good. I have tried the following distros Linux Mint, Sparky Linux, PCLinusOS, Ubuntu Studio 14.04. I am sure I must be doing something wrong somewhere.

Comment: Yes, probably. What computer is it? Brand name and model, graphics chip/card, RAM (size)? Exactly what do you see, when you start the installer? How long do you wait for something to show?

Comment: Please boot from the DVD disk and run the following commands from a terminal  window: `df` ; `sudo lsblk -f` ; `sudo lsblk -m` ; `sudo parted -ls` Then edit your original question to show the output of those commands. Indent each line 4 spaces to render the output as 'code'.

Comment: sudodus, I have posted the requested information. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Computer hardware

I think it is possible to install and run Ubuntu Studio in those computers.

The on-board graphics should work well. The ATI card may or may not work well with Ubuntu Studio, but it should be possible to make at least two of the computers work well.

### Partitions

The partitions on the hard disk drive of the computer, where you ran the commands seem to be linux partitions. What operating system is it (distro name and version (maybe an older version of Ubuntu Studio)?

```
/dev/sda1 -- boot partition
/dev/sda2 -- root partition (I assume)
/dev/sda3 -- swap partition
```

### In the installer

According to your description you were at the *partitioning window -- the **'Something else'** option*, which means manual partitioning, that you should select a root partition and a swap partition.

- If this is what you want, then you can continue by selecting partitions.
- Otherwise, you should

  - go back and select another partitioning option, or
  - exit from the installer and prepare for what you want to do.

---

### Decide what you want to do and/or prepare for it

You need not select 'Something else', you can select one of the other options,

- 'Erase Ubuntu ... and reinstall',
- 'Install Ubuntu ... alongside ...' or
- 'Erase disk and install'.

[image]

- If you intend to keep the operating system, that is already installed in the computers,

  - you can install the new Ubuntu Studio *alongside* the old system.
- If you want Ubuntu Studio to replace the old system,

  - you can let the installer *Erase disk and install* and create partitions and file systems automatically, or
  - you can let the installer *Erase Ubuntu ... and reinstall*.
- You can also create partitions with **gparted** manually before starting the installer, then start the installer and use those partitions. In this case you should

  - select *'Something else'* at the partitioning window and *select root partition and swap partition and where to put the bootloader*. After that you can continue from the 'Something else' window.

[image]

- See also the detailed instructions at this link to the QA testing tracker,

  [Install (manual partitioning) in Ubuntu Desktop amd64 in Xenial 16.04.1 (archived)](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/363/builds/126272/testcases/1302/results)

### About the solution

The OP, @whitelightshadow, found the solution after a discussion in the comments, where I mentioned physical or configuration problems with the hard disk drive, but ruled it out, because I thought it was tested in all three computers mentioned in the question.

So, the OP swapped out the hard disk drive and got no problem at all. The hard disk drive appears not to like Linux, but got no issue with windows on it.

Comment: The Partitions was created by me to see if it will not help the install. I have tried with a blank disk, a ntfs partition, I even installed windows to see if I can get it to install over windows unto the disk. Even gparted didn't help. you see everytime I get to the "Something Else" menu I get the "No root file system is defined, please correct from the partitioning menu" error. And that is where I have been stuck for the last week... I simply can not find the "partitioning menu" it talks about.

Comment: @whitelightshadow, 1. You need not select 'Something else', you can select one of the other options, 'Erase Ubuntu ... and reinstall', 'Install Ubuntu ... alongside ...' or 'Erase disk and install' instead of 'Something else'; or 2. You must **select target partitions** in the 'Something else' window.

Comment: @whitelightshadow, there are pictures and a link with details in the answer now. Good luck :-)

Comment: The installer doesn't give me the first option, the first screen capture at all and the second screen capture looks different. I have added links to screen captures of what I see. I am starting to think the issue might be hardware related. I will swap out the hard drive and see if that sorts out the problem.

Comment: @whitelightshadow, I see. Well, something is seriously wrong. I understand that you want Ubuntu Studio, but as a troubleshooting step, you can *try to install another Ubuntu flavour*. **Xubuntu** has the same desktop environment as Ubuntu Studio, but another set of bundled application programs, so that would be a good choice. I made the screenshots with **Lubuntu** 16.04.1 LTS, which is another good choice. And you can try with standard Ubuntu too.

Comment: @whitelightshadow,  With the current partition table, there might be problems, but it should work with a blank drive (without any partition table). One computer may have physical or configuration problems with the hard disk drive, but the I don't think all three computer have such problems. So something else is wrong, I suspect with the Ubuntu Studio boot drive.

Comment: Swapped out the hard drive and get no problem at all. The hard drive appears not to like Linux got no issue with windows on it... Strange one. I am going to run a full diagnostic on the HDD. And if I find anything I will post it here. Thanx for the help

Comment: @whitelightshadow, You are welcome :-) I'm glad you found the problem, not exactly what I was guessing, but maybe my 'thinking aloud' was helping you along the way.

Comment: Did a full diagnostic on HDD and found nothing wrong. Installed windows 7 no problem. Then tried Ubuntu but it can not find the HDD. One for the X-files I guess. Thanx for everything.