# Ubuntu 18.04 installation stuck on 5th dot

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

After clicking the <kbd>+</kbd> button (see screenshot), the installation seems to be stuck. None of the buttons work, however the top menu works.

[image: stuck installer]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cant get any Ubuntu to install to an internal hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959839/cant-get-any-ubuntu-to-install-to-an-internal-hard-drive)

Comment: I figured it out, after wiping the disc with gparted(it was corrupted), it was fine.

Comment: That's in the 2nd to last section of the accepted answer to the linked duplicate question.